# SystemC constructor, class

Tags: systemc

I am new in systemc. There is one confusion that I am having.

I am creating a `sc_module(hello_world)`. The `sc_ctor(hello_world)` has nothing between the curly braces and I just have a simple `void say_hello()` function inside the module which prints "hello world."

In the `sc_main`, I did this:

```
hello_world hello; 
hello.say_hello();
```

However, I am getting an error that `error C2228: left of '.say_hello' must have class/struct/union.`

I tried this and it worked:

in `sc_main`, I did this:

```
hello_world hello("hi "); 
hello.say_hello();
```

Why it is showing error in the first place? I didn't use one argument constructor.

So, instead of `hello_world hello("hi ")` shouldn't it be `hello_world hello` ? I was just trying to compare with C++ class.

Comment: Hi, can you post the whole module and main code ?

Answer (score 2):

Every SystemC module, whether defined with macro `SC_MODULE` or inherits `sc_module`, needs to have a module name. Constructors of SystemC modules must have one parameter of class `sc_module_name`.

In SystemC standard ([IEEE Std 1666-2011](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf))

> Every class derived (directly or indirectly) from class `sc_module` shall have at least one constructor. Every such constructor shall have one and only one parameter of class `sc_module_name` but may have further parameters of classes other than `sc_module_name`. That parameter is not required to be the first parameter of the constructor.

If you are using macro `SC_CTOR`, it is actually a constructor with one `sc_module_name` parameter!

in sc_module.h:

```
#define SC_CTOR(user_module_name)                           \
    typedef user_module_name SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE;        \
    user_module_name( ::sc_core::sc_module_name )
```

Answer (score 1):

I can´t see nothing wrong.

In fact, it seems to me, that you have the same code like this example -> http://www.asic-world.com/systemc/first1.html

I hope you could check your with this one.

Answer (score 1):

The macro `SC_CTOR` has created a `hello(const sc_module_name name&)` constructor for you. Therefor the compiler will not generate a default constructor for you to call and the object hello cannot be created.

Answer (score 0):

Inbuilt constructor after macro expansion must have an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you defined your constructor as private. As a result compiler cannot name it from main.cpp.